# Saving thumbnails images to certain directory

Tags: php

I'm willing to use thumbnails into my website which is mainly like websites directory.
I've been thinking to save url thumbnails into certain directory !

Example :-

I'm going to use free websites thumbnails service that gives me code to show thumbnail image of any URL as follow

```
<img src='http://thumbnails_provider.com/code=MY_ID&url=ANY_SITE.COM'/>
```

This would show the thumbnail of `ANY_SITE.COM`

i want to save the generate thumbnail image into certain directory `my_site.com/thumbnails`

Why i'm doing this ?

in fact my database table is like `my_table {id,url,image}` where i'm going to give the image thumbnail random name and store its new name into `my_table` related to its url then i can call it back anytime and i know how to do it but i don't know how to save it into certain directory.

any help ~thanks

Comment: I think i should also give it certain id='something' and by somehow i can save it

Comment: Does the thumbnail provider have an API?

Comment: @Paul yes it is, "code=MY_ID" this would me my API ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cURL should work for you:

```
$file = 'the URL';

$ch = curl_init ($file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$fullpath = 'path to destination';

$fp = fopen($fullpath);
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: ~ thanks but i guess there is something wrong with the code !’x' and } and what you meant by $fullpath .

Comment: See edits. The above code is only a guideline, not complete. It should give you the right idea...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) to fetch the remote image.  You can save it with `curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_FILE, '/my/image/path/here.jpg');`.  The id could be something simple like a hash of the original URL.  Obviously you'd have to check to make sure the directories exist before you save the file (using `is_dir()` and creating them with `mkdir()` if they don't).